# Java SDK support for Vulkan in Android

Tags: java, android, vulkan

Android supports OpenGL ES both through its framework API (Java SDK) and the Native Development Kit (NDK).

Is there support for Vulkan Graphics API on the Android SDK (Java) platform? Or is the Vulkan supported only with NDK? If there is no such Java SDK support, maybe it is planned in the future? Thanks in advance!